# Finding upper bound of number of prime numbers in arithmetic progressions

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

In $2004$, Green and Tao proved the following amazing result on prime numbers:

> for any given $N$, there exists an arithmetic progression of length  $N$ consisting of prime numbers only.

Tao won a Fields Medal in 2006.

I am wondering, can we use it in any way to find the maximum length of arithmetic progressions consisting of prime numbers only whose initial term is predefined?
 $i.e.$ imagine the initial term of the progression is $5$.
 How to find out the maximum length of any arithmetic progression consisting only of prime numbers?

Comment: This is a good research question, but I doubt you'll get a good answer on MSE.  Anyway, the Green-Tao theorem and its proof are very much existence oriented; fixing an initial term would be a much harder problem.

Comment: However I found this question in a totally beinner courses. It is the very first homework.